# Error in R using neuralnet package

Tags: r, neural-network, r-package

I'm running a script to estimate a Neural Network in R using the package *neuralnet*.

I'm using a Linux OS and the script is the following:

```
# useful libraries
library("XLConnect")  
library("neuralnet")

# data loading;
DATA = loadWorkbook("/home/quant/Desktop/D.xlsx") # loading sheet;
DATASET = readWorksheet(NN_DATA, sheet = "D") # reading sheet;

NN_DATASET # display the directory;
head(NN_DATASET) # show data;
warnings() # error detection & data quality;

#test set detection;
testset <- NN_DATASET[1:101, ] 

# building the neural networks;
NNET <- neuralnet(y ~ MKTVALUER +  VOLR  + DYR +    PER +   DJR +   DAXR +  MSCIR + NIKKEIR +   CCOR +  CPIR +  CABCR + EGR +   USFFR + USGDPR +    GCIR +  IGR +   IPR +   IRR +   MCURNR +    M2R +   NOMANUFACTORINGR +  PCER +  POPR +  PPIR +  CBLEIR +    DEBTR + UR +    C_XAU + C_XAG + BARCLAYSAGG +   C_USDJPY +  C_EURUSD, NN_DATASET, hidden = 2, lifesign = "minimal", linear.output = FALSE, threshold = 0.1)
```

Everything goes right till the last line, in which R gives an **error** output, as follows:

```
Error in x - y : non-conformable arrays
```

The **dataframe structure**, got by using `str(NN_DATASET)` is the following:

```
'data.frame':   201 obs. of  34 variables:
 $ DATA            : chr  "Q4 1964" "Q1 1965" "Q2 1965" "Q3 1965" ...
 $ SP500_R         : num  NA 0.0184 -0.0215 0.0622 0.025 ...
 $ MKTVALUER       : num  NA 0.0257 -0.0206 0.0694 0.0215 ...
 $ VOLR            : num  NA 0.007336 0.000982 0.007239 -0.003561 ...
 $ DYR             : num  NA NA 0.0294 -0.0528 0.0366 ...
 $ PER             : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ DJR             : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ DAXR            : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ MSCIR           : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ NIKKEIR         : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ CCOR            : num  NA 0.0338 0.0322 0.0247 0.0192 ...
 $ CPIR            : num  NA 0 0.4654 0 0.0565 ...
 $ CABCR           : num  NA -0.2793 0.2268 -0.1893 -0.0123 ...
 $ EGR             : num  NA -0.0895 0.1666 -0.0579 0.0681 ...
 $ USFFR           : num  NA 0.1034 0.02733 -0.00245 0.02427 ...
 $ USGDPR          : num  NA 0.0293 0.0182 0.024 0.0301 ...
 $ GCIR            : num  NA 0.00572 0.01759 0.04266 0.0346 ...
 $ IGR             : num  NA -0.02768 0.10641 0.00942 0.05768 ...
 $ IPR             : num  NA 0.0371 0.0229 0.0207 0.02 ...
 $ IRR             : num  NA 0.00218 0.06536 -0.06318 0.111 ...
 $ MCURNR          : num  NA -0.00201 0.00977 0.01819 0.02592 ...
 $ M2R             : num  NA 0.0166 0.0115 0.0156 0.0186 ...
 $ NOMANUFACTORINGR: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ PCER            : num  NA 0.0252 0.0159 0.0208 0.0309 ...
 $ POPR            : num  NA 0.00255 0.00294 0.00352 0.00296 ...
 $ PPIR            : num  NA 0.00297 0.0118 0.00293 0.00873 ...
 $ CBLEIR          : num  NA 0.0224 0.0172 0.0135 0.0272 ...
 $ DEBTR           : num  NA -0.000955 -0.000637 -0.002553 0.013329 ...
 $ UR              : num  NA -0.0202 -0.0417 -0.066 -0.0706 ...
 $ C_XAU           : num  NA 0.00057 0 0 0 ...
 $ C_XAG           : num  NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BARCLAYSAGG     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ C_USDJPY        : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ C_EURUSD        : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Browsing on the internet I found a lot of answers here in stackoverflow.com, but, in each case, the solution is different, so, O posted a new question. Please, do not mark it as duplicate, because it is not.

The script is based on one found on [R-Bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-neural-networks-for-credit-scoring-a-simple-example/)

Any help, hint or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be best if you could make a reproducible example (not just so we can run the code, but it will make you think about the data structures you're using) or at least show the structure of the objects you're using (use function `str()`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the post @RomanLuštrik. May the problem is due to the fact there're a lot of missing, as suggested in other answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see `y` column, that you're referring in your formula, in your data set. Your target variable should exist in your data set. Should it be `SP500_R`?

Second, `neuralnet` won't work with `NAs` in data, filter your data set with `na.omit()` first.

Also, let me give a side note: if I got right what your data is, you'll got nothing from that kind of analysis.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I reported y in the place of SP500R for simplicity. In any case, the code does not work anyway! I will eliminate all NAs and I will update the results. Thanks for the comment @cyberj0g!

Comment: Yes, missing values are the reason for which *neuralnet* gives an error as output. I did not understand why is it. Could you be able to explain that?

Comment: The short answer is: because NA handling is not supported in that particular implementation of ANN. However, accept the fact that most implementations of machine learning algorithms cannot do that too, and you should handle NA's somehow during data pre-processing step.

Comment: Ok, thank you again for the last answer too! +1 and marked answered!