# Error in neuralnet package with setpmax and threshold

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to fit a Neural Network in `R` with `neuralnet` package and have some issues:

> Error in while (step < stepmax && reached.threshold > threshold) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I'm trying this so far:

```r
n <- names(training)
formula.rna <- as.formula(paste('ID_MAU ~', paste(n[!n %in% 'ID_MAU'], collapse = ' + ')))

> formula.rna
ID_MAU ~ CD_POR + CL_1_LI + CL_1_LC + CL_1_LS + CL_1_LG + CL_1_ET + 
    CL_1_CD + CL_1_EFCP + CL_1_EFLP + CL_1_GEFCP + CL_1_GICP + 
    CL_1_ROE + CL_1_ROI + CL_1_MB + CL_1_MO + CL_1_ML + CL_1_LPA + 
    CL_1_PD + CL_1_MOD_ELI + CL_1_MOD_KAN + X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + 
    X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10 + X11 + X12 + X13 + X14 + X15 + 
    X16 + X17 + X20 + X21 + X22 + X23
```

```r
# ANN
training$ID_MAU <- factor(training$ID_MAU)
set.seed(016238)
fit.rna <- neuralnet(formula.rna,
                     , data=training
                     , hidden=7
                     , linear.output = F
                     , threshold=0.01
                     , stepmax=1e6
                     , rep = 2
)
```

Can someone help me explain why this happen?

Comment: Please check `summary (data)`. I think your data contains missing values.

Comment: neuralnet won't work with NAs in data, filter your data set with `na.omit()` first. You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021508/error-in-r-using-neuralnet-package

Comment: There is no missing values in my df, i filter as you say with `na.omit()`, but get the same error.

Comment: NA and Inf behaves almost same way.

Comment: Yes, thank you! After check `summary(training)` i could solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by just removing a variable that had `-Inf` value:

```r
summary(training$X21)

Min. 1st Qu.  Median   Mean  3rd Qu.    Max. 
-Inf -2.7411 -1.7210   -Inf  -0.7679  1.6921
```